# Cookie set on one page is not retained on other pages using Javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies, mootools

I have set a cookie:

```
Cookie.write('callstream', new Date, {
    path: '/',
    duration: 14,
    secure: false,
});
```

The cookie is set correctly on the page where i set the cookie, however once i visit a new page on the same domain the cookie is now NULL

FIXED:

Needed to ADD:

domain: '.domain.com'

Comment: While I'm not sure this is the issue (hence the comment) the mootools page says `In order to share the cookie with pages located in a different path, the Cookie.options.domain value must be set.` from [here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Utilities/Cookie#Cookie-options)

Comment: Yes you are correct.  I was able to fix this by setting the domain in the Cookie.write and also in Cookie.dispose to be something like this: '.subdomain.com' and that fixed the issue

Comment: Awesome, added it as an answer for future reference :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you aren't setting the domain when writing the cookie, as shown here:

```
Cookie.write('callstream', new Date, {
    path: '/',
    duration: 14,
    secure: false,
    domain: '.domain.com'
});
```

Comment: You really need to be clear about it - if you are using the same domain - meaning `www.domain.com/page1` and `www.domain.com/page2` then you don't have to add the `domain` option - if you are using subdomains then you do - your answer is a bit confusing to some people.